# How to set the max connection pool size in apache ignite?

Tags: ignite

How can i set the maximum connection pool size in apache ignite, using the ignite configuration file?? I m unable to find the methods to set the connection pool size.

Comment: Using JDBCClient i m able to set the connection pool size, but through apache ignite is it possible to set???

Comment: It's not clear what is the expected action of the setting that you are searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ClientConnectorConfiguration#threadPoolSize](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ClientConnectorConfiguration.html#setThreadPoolSize-int-) to specify size of the thread pool, that is used for JDBC SQL query processing. ClientConnectorConfiguration should be provided as [IgniteConfiguration#clientConnectorConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setClientConnectorConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration-) property.

Comment: Is the Connection objects in jdbc and creating this threadPoolSize are same in terms of concept????

Comment: This setting specifies how many threads the Ignite node uses to serve JDBC connections. On the other hand, JDBC driver on the client side uses only one thread to interact with the server. So, if you want the client side to use more threads, you should start multiple JDBC connections.

Comment: Can u please tell me the difference between the Connection objects and thread pools???

Comment: Do you mean `java.sql.Connection`? It's created on the client side, but thread pool, that I mentioned in the answer, affects thread pool size on the server side.

Comment: How will i set the number of connection objects in apache ignite??? Can it be achieved only through the jdbcClient???

Comment: This is a JDBC client configuration, so it cannot be specified on Ignite side. You have to create connections yourself or use a JDBC connection pool.

Comment: Ok Denis, I got it now. Thank u for ur time and clear explaination Denis...

Comment: As I already said, you can limit number of threads used on Ignite nodes. But the JDBC driver can be used only in a single thread, so you should create multiple connections manually.

Comment: Each connection will be associated with a separate thread on server. But you should take care of it yourself on a client side.